# Highcarts function not being recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am trying to implement a pie chart using `Highcharts` on our site and I keep getting this error:  `

> TypeError: $(...).highcharts is not a function
>   $('#container').highcharts({

I am calling the all necessary files before the code and have the code in a `ready` function but that hasn't made a difference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../site/js/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({
```

Comment: check if your referenced js file path is correct

Comment: @yongwu file path is correct and highcharts.js is present

Comment: Try loading highcharts.js from their site `<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>` does it work? Fiddle works: http://jsfiddle.net/u5ftq820/ Broken reference is the most likely reason, as @yongwu above suggested.

Comment: Thanks @Zealander!! I must have an out of date version of highcharts

Comment: Or using out of date jquery. I think you need at least jquery 1.10 for highcharts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using an out of date version of `highcharts.js`